# Tensorflow TypeError: export_savedmodel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'graph_rewrite_specs'

Tags: python, tensorflow

My tensorflow version is 1.8.

In simple words, when I try to use tf.contrib.learn.KMeansClustering.export_savedmodel() method, I got this error.

The [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNLinearCombinedRegressor#export_savedmodel) shows that this method actually has an argument graph_rewrite_specs.

My code is basically:

```
kmeans = tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering(num_clusters=num_clusters,
                                      model_dir='model', 
                                      use_mini_batch=True,
                                      mini_batch_steps_per_iteration=1)

# training code here...

kmeans.export_savedmodel('saved', 
                         serving_input_receiver_fn, 
                         as_text=False,
                         graph_rewrite_specs=(GraphRewriteSpec((tag_constants.SERVING,tag_constants.TRAINING), ()),))
```

Is there any problem in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are checking the wrong documentations,those docs are [DnnLinearRegressor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNLinearCombinedRegressor#export_savedmodel) whereas you are using [KmeanClustering](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeansClustering) that has method signature
of

```
export_savedmodel(
export_dir_base,
serving_input_receiver_fn,
assets_extra=None,
as_text=False,
checkpoint_path=None,
strip_default_attrs=False)
```

DnnLinearRegressor and KmeanClustering inherits from [Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Estimator) but Dnn overrides export_savedmodel whereas KmeanClustering keeps the original function`s signature inherited from Estimator

Comment: oh... i did not notice that. It seems like I open multiple doc pages, and looked up on wrong page unconsciously. Thanks very much. Do you know how to achieve same function of graph_rewrite_specs with the KMeansClustering's export_savedmodel method.

Comment: I am not sure graph_specs but it seems it's how the model is named and indexed,honestly I am not sure why Dnn has it